# data compression undecidability

Tags: string, algorithm

I am reading about undecidablity in data compression in book Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick.

Undecidability.

> Consider the million-bit string. This string appears to be random, so
>   you are not likely to find a lossless compression algorithm that will
>   compress it. But there is a way to represent that string with just a
>   few thousand bits, because it was produced by the program below.

```
public class RandomBits
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int x = 11111;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
x = x * 314159 + 218281;
BinaryStdOut.write(x > 0);
}
BinaryStdOut.close();
}
}
```

> (This program is an exampleof a pseudo-random number generator, like
>   Java’s Math.random() method.) A compression algorithm that compresses
>   by writing the program in ASCII and expands by reading the program and
>   then running it achieves a .3 percent compression ratio, which is
>   difficult to beat (and we can drive the ratio arbitrarily low by
>   writing more bits). To compress such a file is to discover the program
>   that produced it.
>
> This example is not so far-fetched as it first appears: when you
>   compress a video or an old book that was digitized with a scanner or
>   any of countless other types of files from the web, you are
>   discovering something about the program that produced the file. The
>   realization that much of the data that we process is produced by a
>   program leads to deep issues in the theory of computation and also
>   gives insight into the challenges of data compression.
>
> For example, it is possible to prove that optimal data compression
>   (find the shortest program to produce a given string) is an
>   undecidable problem: not only can we not have an algorithm that
>   compresses every bitstream, but also we cannot have a strategy for
>   developing the best algorithm!

1. What does author mean by "you are discovering some thing about the program that produced the file" from examples given above this line?
2. What does author mean by "program leads to deep issues in the theory of computation"?
3. What does author mean by "find the shortest program to produce a given string" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) The author means that to compress a bit-stream you search for an implementation of the algorithm that produced this bit-stream. Then you store the implementation's source text as a compressed form of that bit-stream: to recreate original bit-stream you just compile and run a program.

2) I have no this book, so I can't tell you.

3) The same as 1), literally: you search for a shortest program that produces a given bit-stream. The source code of this program would be a compressed form of a bit-stream.

Comment: (Item 2) may be outdated with the plethora of videos stored every day. The author may be referring to the "equivalence" of the output of a process to its input&program.)